# Can I link a predefined string to an input in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-apps, google-apps-script-editor

I want to make an inventory program (while I have few to zero programming skills)
The Goal is to create barcodes for the devices that are borrowable.
1. When some1 wants to borrow a device there is a staff member who scans the barcode and fills in a google form.(name, quantity, barcode(s)
2. The google form links to a spreadsheet where the magic happens.
3. The magic happens. I mean my spreadsheet manages incoming and outgoing devices and there is a sheet where I can see which device has not come back to me yet.

This is all working fine. Except for the following problem.
I want that when Google Spreadsheet sees the barcode in the cell it changes it into a string (the name of the device e.g. Chromebook)

My questions:
1. Is this possible
2. HOW? :)

UPDATE

Spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jX-ufX6M7sMAvifzZUKeERR3XzQBNxMu5GpnfqvK8kE/edit#gid=1502342008

The barcodes are printed and pasted on every device. We have Champtek handheld scanners to scan the barcodes. And that part seems to work. The scanned content shows in forms. When the form is submitted it shows in google spreadsheets but then I need to link the device name to the barcode somehow.

If you need more info, please reply

Thanks in advance!
(I'm a teacher in a school in Belgium trying to digitalise a few things)

Comment: Are barcodes images in your sheets? or what exactly? Can you provide a sample of the your spreadsheet with a barcode? Please remove any sensitive info before posting it, INTO your question. Thanks

Comment: If the barcodes are in the sheet 'barcodes' (ik begon daaraan te twijfelen) then I think you could do something with 'my' code.

Answer (score 1):

You want a barcode replaced by the name of the device to which the barcode belong? So that you know which kind of device is borrowed or returned but not which specific device is borrowed or returned?

```
function barcodes(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var barcodesSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Barcodes");
var barcodeValues = barcodesSheet.getRange("A1:C").getValues().filter(function(row){return row[0] !== ""});

var firstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses Check-Out");
var firstSheetRange = firstSheet.getRange(1,1,firstSheet.getLastRow(),firstSheet.getLastColumn());
var firstSheetValues = firstSheetRange.getValues();

  for(var i=0;i<firstSheetValues.length;i++){

    var firstSheetRow = firstSheetValues[i];

      for(var f=3;f<firstSheetRow.length;f++){

      var barcode = firstSheetRow[f];

        for(var b=0;b<barcodeValues.length;b++){

          if(barcodeValues[b][0] == barcode){

            var device = barcodeValues[b][2];

            firstSheet.getRange(i+1,f+1).setValue(device);

          }

        }

      }

  }

}
```

If I where you I would add the name of the device to the barcode (AAA-aaa-111, Chromebook).

How do you import the barcode into the Google Form?

I don't think this answers your question since yoy want to know how to change a barcode (how doe a barcode look like in a Google Spreadsheet cell) into a string? Sorry.

Comment: I import barcodes into Google form by using a Champtek Handheld scanner. So I open the Google form, I take the chromebook or Ipad device and scan the physical barcode on the device. Then it appears in the text field on Google Forms. I submit the form and all the scanned barcodes appear in Spreadsheets. Then I need to link that barcode to a device type so I know which device is being lend.

Comment: My comment above should be here I think.

Comment: I tried your code but it didn't do anything. (So I am probably doing something wrong).

Comment: @JellePoelmans I made a copy of the copy and tried the script. There are not yet barcodes in the first sheet ("Form Responses Check-Out").  If you fill in some barcodes you will see it works.

Comment: Works perfectly! Can I give you a thumbs up somewhere? ; )